# Jenkins slave not restarted on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, openshift

I'm quite new on OpenShift. I've got a free plan on OpenShift with a NodeJs app, built by Jenkins (also hosted on OpenShift).

**Since yesterday, I'm not able to launch a build (manualy or after a git push) because the slave node isn't restarted after idle.**

And when I manualy launch the build, the build stay in the queue during something like 30 secondes then it disappears.

My 4 last build failed because of :

```
FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
```

Maybe it's linked (some restriction by Openshift for free plan , or I don't know).

Do you have any idea why my slave node doesn't restart, and / or how can y force this restart to launch my build.

Thanks

Comment: I'm also having this issue. It seems that the slave gets hung at that point. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No I didn't find a solution. The only one solution is to delete the Jenkins cartridge and to recreate it... Bad solution.